# React Context - Reset itself to default value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, react-context

I'm working on react context. I am creating a context to store the user info from the server, it is storing it fine but there is a wired situation here. Whenever I refresh the page, it reset itself to the default value which is in my case `undefined` and I am not sure why.

Here is the userContext

```js
import React from "react";

const UserContext = React.createContext();

export default UserContext;
```

Here is the code for UserProvider

```js
import { useEffect, useState, useContext, useMemo } from "react";
import UserContext from "./userContext";
import axios from "axios";

const UserProvider = (props) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    

    const userLogin = () => {
        axios.defaults.headers.common = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`}
        axios
        .get("/auth/profile")
        .then((res)=>{
          setUser(res.data)
        })
    }

    const userLogout = () => {
        setUser(null)
    }

    const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({user, userLogin, userLogout}), [user, userLogin, userLogout] )

    return(
        <UserContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
            { props.children }
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default UserProvider
```

The purpose of the userLogin function is to get the info of the user. and the userLogout is to reset the user info to null.

Here is how I implemented it in the App.js

```js
function App() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  
  return (
    
      <BrowserRouter>
      <UserProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Welcome />}></Route>
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />}></Route>
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <Route path="/goal" element={<UserGoals />}></Route>
        </Routes>
        </UserProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

I will not bother you with the details of the rest of the application but I will share with you how I use it in other components

```js
const LoginForm = () => {
  const {user, userLogin, userLogout} = useContext(UserContext)

}
```

Whenever I log in, I just simply call the function `userLogin` and whenever I want to access the user, I access it using `user`.

The problem occurs after call `userLogin` and then refreshing the page, the `user` becomes `undefined`. it occurs in multiple pages not only in the login page.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

Most likely it's because you are not calling the `userLogin` function when the app first runs.

try adding this in UserProvider

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) {
    userLogin()
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: is in't going to run everytime the component mount? in that case there will be many calls to the server.

Comment: The `UserProvider` component is at top level, so it will mount only once. Plus there is a check. As you can see the `userLogin` function only gets called if there is no user. After the user is set, the function will not be invoked again.

Comment: The purpose of the user is not only to hold the info of the user but also to work as an indicator if the user is logged in or out. in that case if the user is logged out, the user will be logged in again whenever they refresh the page.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. Could you please be more specific to what is your intention? What I understand from your code, is that you have a token and you are using this token to fetch the information of the user. This MUST happen every time the user refreshes the page. Unless you want to store the user information in localStorage instead of the token, something nobody would suggest you to do.

Comment: If you are concerned of the user refreshing the page too many times, you need to handle this case in your server, by setting a limit on the requests per minute or per second.